# VBA - Variable Not updating after a second run of the macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Okay, so I have a spreadsheet in which I am trying to copy as a new sheet then re-name as a value of a cell on the original spreadsheet. When I run the macro the first time, it works fine. Ever subsequent time, however, it gives me the "Name is already taken" error and tries to pass the value of the original variable (x) again instead of taking the new value in cell C2.

I am self-taught and still fairly new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.I feel like the error might be coming in my range reference, as in there is a different way to declare the variable (x) to that cells' value that I might be missing.

```
 Sub freezesheet()
    Dim x As String

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    x = Range("C2:C2").Value
    Debug.Print (x)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Sheets(3)
    Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Name = x
    x = ""

    Debug.Print (x)

    Cells.Select
    selection.Copy
    selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're naming a worksheet, and every worksheet must have a unique name.  Because you're getting the worksheet name from C2, if the value in C2 didn't change then you are trying to give a worksheet a duplicate name which will cause the error you've described.  Make sure you're not trying to assign a duplicate worksheet name.

Comment: After running the macro, the active sheet in the workbook will be the copy. If you update cell C2 on that sheet, running the macro again will give you the error described because the script is going to look at cell C2 on Sheet1. Is there a chance you made this mistake?

Comment: @tigeravatar - I am changing cell C2 every time I'm trying to update it. E.g. cell C2 on the first run is 10011-01, I change it on the second run to 10011-02 on Sheet 1, but it still gives me the same error then when I return to Sheet 1, The macro has replaced 10011-02 with the original 10011-01.

Comment: @phhlho - Doesn't my activation call on Sheet 1 make this irrelevant? I am updating Cell C2 on Sheet 1 every time, not the copy, and I don't want people to use the copy to update again, they should always be using Sheet 1 to do work, then the button essentially freezes a copy of their work and paste as values into a new sheet which allows us to see the changes made at the time.

Comment: @cdipaola The activation will make sure you pull the value from Sheet1 - the problem is if whoever changes the value of C2 doesn't change the value on Sheet1. I raised this as a possibility of what's happening, because the first thing that I did when I tried that macro was to accidentally edit the copy, not Sheet1 and I received that same error. After making sure I was changing the value of C2 on Sheet1 in between each run, the script appeared to be working as expected.

Comment: @phhlho - Good to know, I will see if that was what I was doing, just maybe not realizing it! Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There cannot be two sheets with the same name. So when you are running the code second time, the new sheet added will be renamed on the basis of cell C2 from Sheet1.

Also you can shorten your code like this...

```
Sub freezesheet()
   Dim x As String

   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   x = Range("C2").Value

   Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Sheets(3)
   ActiveSheet.Name = x
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
```

The above code will run without an issue if you change the C2 value each time before running the code next time.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding if a user were to update sheet 1 Cell C2 multiple times and try and press the button assigned to this macro after each edit of cell C2, this will then edit each sheet to be a newly named sheet?
`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value`
Will this then only keep values and take out any formulas used?

Comment: So now I'm getting an error "RunTime Error '1004':

and when I open the debugger it's pointing at the code 

`activesheet.usedrange.value = activesheet.usedrange.value`

Comment: Yes it will convert all the formulas to their values on the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting error 1004. The code works perfectly fine at my end.

Comment: You are actually super correct. I had my sheet protected and It wasn't allowing that piece of the code to run. Your code works perfectly! Thank you!